# Avro - 'string' datatype in output JSON for optional field

Tags: java, avro

I am beginner to Avro. This is my sample Avro schema where 'age' field is an optional.  Generated Java stubs out of it.

For optional field 'age' the output JSON looks different, how can i remove "string" datatype appearing in the JSON. I don't want to keep it as `"default": "undefined"` either.
If i don't provide 'age' value, then in the JSON, age field shouldn't be visible.

Actual JSON

```
{
  "id" : "111",
  "name" : "myname",
  "age" : {
    "string" : "25"
  }
}
```

Expected JSON:

```
{
  "id" : "111",
  "name" : "myname",
  "age": "25"      
}
```

Avro Schema:

```
{
    "name": "Employee",
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "com.mycompany.employee",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "name",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "age",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
            ],
            "default": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Code to generate JSON :

```
public class EmployeeValidate {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Employee employee = Employee.newBuilder().setId("111")
                .setName("myname").setAge("25").build();

        System.out.println("Before encoder : " + employee.toString());

        Encoder encoder;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(Employee.getClassSchema(), byteStream, true);
        employee.customEncode(encoder);
        encoder.flush();

        System.out.println("After encoder : " + byteStream.toString("UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

output:

```
Before encoder : {"id": "111", "name": "myname", "age": "25"}

After encoder : {
  "id" : "111",
  "name" : "myname",
  "age" : {
    "string" : "25"
  }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.0</version>
</dependency>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>schema</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/</sourceDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can i remove "string" datatype appearing in the JSON

[You can't](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/#schema-declaration). Otherwise, Avro won't know what type of the union to deserialize as.

> don't want to keep it as "default": "undefined"

You shouldn't have to.

> If i don't provide 'age' value, then in the JSON, age field shouldn't be visible.

It shouldn't be. You've set age as a nullable field, so just don't set it.

Overall, it's not really clear why you'd use Avro only to get JSON output when there are other strictly JSON libraries

Comment: 'Avro won't know what type of the union to deserialize as.' In that case, how is Avro deserializing id and age fields?  We are using GCP Pub/Sub Avro schema. The output JSON looks a bit weird, especially the optional fields. All the optional fields (ex: age) have additional flower brackets and string type before the value (treating it as an object field). My actual JSON has nearly 60 fields, out of which 40 are optional.  Final JSON looks cumbersome with these additional brackets as shown for the 'age' field. I was searching for an elegant solution where my final JSON looks like a normal JSON.

Comment: I have edited my question, now added 'Expected JSON' and 'Actual JSON'

Comment: Sure, I understood what you expected, but that's not possible for the reasons mentioned. The Avro parser needs to iterate types of unioned fields to deserialize; the only way to find that type is to check the key of the object... The ID does not have a union, so that will work as-is. So, your Pub/Sub consumer will now need to use Avro's JSON DecoderFactory to parse the JSON into any downstream Avro model. Or, overall, you could just not use JSON, and stick with binary Avro (the data in Pub/Sub topics doesn't need to be human-readable)